# Liferay Control panel programmatic access

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to fetch the setting value of the email reply address with:

`PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS)`

But this returns the original value from the `portal-ext.properties` file, which has since been updated in the Control panel to a different value.

What `*Service` or `*Util` do I use to access settings in the Liferay control panel?

I've hunted through the source of Liferay but I can't seem to find a way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PrefsPropsUtil` instead of `PropsUtil`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16621120)

Comment: You may be right about this but question asked here is `What *Service or *Util do I use to access settings in the Liferay control panel?
`